# Reproducir un sonido en HTML al pulsar un botón

Tags: javascript, html, html5, audio

Quiero hacer un botón que reproduzca un audio en HTML, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

He intentado hacer esto:

```html
<button style="" onclick="<audio src="miaudio.mp3"></audio>"></button>
```

¿Alguien me puede decir como se hace?

Comment: Vas a necesitar implementar javascript te dejo el ejemplo que estas buscando espero que te sirva de ayuda https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_play

Answer (score 5):

**OPCIÓN 1**

- Al botón recuperalo por medio de una variable
- A la variable que representa al botón dale un *listener* al evento `click`
- Por dentro de la función vamos a crear un nuevo elemento en el DOM el cual será una etiqueta de `audio`
- A la etiqueta de audio necesitamos establecerle el valor al atributo `src` que es de donde va a leer el navegador el audio que planeas reproducir
- A la variable que tiene asignada la creacíon del audio dale acceso al método `play()`

Código

```
<button class="reproductor">Reproduce tu audio</button>
<script>
    let boton = document.querySelector(".reproductor")

    boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let etiquetaAudio = document.createElement("audio")
      etiquetaAudio.setAttribute("src", "ubicación de tu archivo de audio")
      etiquetaAudio.play()
    })
</script>
```

Entonces cada vez que presiones el botón el audio se reproducirá

**OPCIÓN 2**

Estuve checando y considero que estar creando un elemento para el DOM cada vez que se presiona el botón puede no ser la mejor opción.

Entonces:

- Declaramos una etiqueta audio son el atributo `src` vacío
- Recuperamos a dicha etiqueta en una variable
- Por dentro de la función recuperamos a la variable y le asignamos un valor a su atributo `src`

---

```
<button class="reproductor">Reproduce tu audio</button>
<audio src=""></audio>
<script>
    let boton = document.querySelector(".reproductor")
    let audioEtiqueta = document.querySelector("audio")

    boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      audioEtiqueta.setAttribute("src", "ruta_a_tu_archivo")
      audioEtiqueta.play()
      console.log(`Reproduciendo: ${audioEtiqueta.src}`)
    })
</script>
```

**Referencias**

- [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [etiqueta de audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

Comment: Bonito, simple y bien realizado, deben haber mas respuestas asi por parte de la comunidad, muy bien beta.

Comment: ¿Por qué definir el audio con src vacío? El audio debería tener una fuente, de lo contrario, al pulsar el botón puede haber un retraso la primera vez que se pulse (ya que al no especificar el fichero, éste no se habrá descargado y antes de reproducirse tendrá que descargarse). Si quieres asegurarte que no se va a reproducir, puedes ponerle el atributo `autoplay` con valor `false`. Pero de ese modo, el archivo se descargará al principio y te asegurarás que no habrá lag (o no será tan malo como podría ser).

Comment: Agradezco la observación @AlvaroMontoro solo que colocaré que el atributo será `autostart=0` ya que con `autoplay` lo seguía reproduciendo aún con el valor de false

Comment: Hmmm.... eso puede ser porque `autoplay` es un valor booleano (si lo pones, incluso con el valor "false", será verdadero porque la cadena "false" es truthy). Me imagino que el valor por defecto es falso y si no lo pones, no debería sonar. `autostart` no es un atributo válido para [`audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio).

Comment: Y si quiero que sean 2 o más botones ¿Cómo le hago?

Answer (score 1):

O simplemente con el evento play() puedes usar para reproducir el audio:

```html
<audio id="m" src="miaudio.mp3" controls=""></audio>
<br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('m').play()">Play</button>
```

Comment: Pero si no quieres ver los controles, solo le quitas controls